# How to add action column in ag grid having edit/delete button for each row in react?

Tags: reactjs, grid

I have been working on a project in ReactJs where the delete button is required for every row to perform specific delete/edit operation.
Any other grid structure having row-wise edit/delete function will also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such specific method which I have found till now! instead, use table format to display rowdata

Answer (score 0):

let's say that you have a posts component, and you want add delete action to each post:

```
const Posts = () => {
  const posts_array = [...]
  
  const deletePost(post_id) => {
    delete(post_id)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {posts_array.map(
        (post) => <Post 
                    post_data={post} 
                    key={post.id} 
                    handle_delete={()=>deletePost(post.id)}
                  />
      )}
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```